# settimeout issue in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, settimeout

I am facing a strange issue while using javascript setTimeout function in IE8.
I want to use the 'setTimeout' function like this -

```
setTimeout(timeout,2000, {name:'saarthak'});

    function timeout(opts)
    {       
        alert('hello ' + opts.name);
    }
```

the third parameter of the setTimeout is the argument that I want to pass to the calling function. This is working perfect fine in FF, Chrome but not in IE8.

Does anybody have any clue what could be done? Or any work around of achieving this?

Thanks

Comment: You could've been finding it yourself: *Note that passing additional parameters to the function in the first syntax does not work in Internet Explorer.* @https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably not supported there, so have this instead:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    timeout({name:'saarthak'});
},2000);
```

Meaning call your function from within anonymous function.

Comment: yup, thats what I managed to do. Thanks anyway Shadow wizard. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to call *timeout* with changing variable (e.g. calling *timeout* in loop with lot of names) you can use also in IE8:

```
var names = ["saarthak", "saarthak2", "saarthak3"]; 
for (var q in names) {
  setTimeout(
    (function(opts){
          return function(){
                    alert ("hello " + opts.name)            
                  }
     })({name:names[q]}), 2000);
}
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/q4HYz/

Comment: Wow, in 2022 I still need this workaround 