# Problems with setTimeout and reloading iframes

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm trying to change the src of an iframe every 2 seconds with different page but I failed miserably so far. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code? It only loads the last file, 5.html and not the other ones, 1.html 2.html 3.html and 4.html

```
function reloadiframe(nbr) {
    setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById("iframe").src = nbr + ".html";
    }, 2000);
}

function reload() {

    for (i=1;i<=5;i++) {
            reloadiframe(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at using setInterval that is a better approach

Comment: @Aknosis can you explain to me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` does not wait. The timeouts all fire at pretty much exactly the same time, since they are all started at pretty much exactly the same time. Just a small change will fix the problem:

```
function reloadiframe(nbr) {
    setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById("iframe").src = nbr + ".html";
    }, 2000*i); // <== right here
}

function reload() {

    for (i=1;i<=5;i++) {
            reloadiframe(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're now delaying the reload for two seconds. Page 1, 2, 3 and 4 actually get loaded, but are quickly overwritten by frame 5.

Either use `setTimeout` in `reloadiframe` to delay the next reload, use `setInterval` to periodically reload the iframe or increase the timeout:

```
function reloadiframe(nbr) {
    document.getElementById("iframe").src = nbr + ".html";
    if (n <= 5) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            reloadiframe(nbr + 1);
        }, 2000);
    }
}
function reload() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        reloadiframe(i);
    }, 2000);
}
```

Alternative using `setInterval`:

```
var timer, nbr;
function reloadiframe() {
    document.getElementById("iframe").src = nbr + ".html";
    if (nbr > 5) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}
function reload() {
    nbr = 1;
    timer = setInterval(reloadiframe, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Passing extra parameters through `setTimeout` does not work in IE. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout

Comment: @MattBall: Really? Even in recent versions after IE6?

Comment: I was just passing along what MDC said - I'm on a Mac, so I can't test this myself.

Comment: That's dumb. And looking at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7007364/427545), it's still unsupported even in IE8 >.< I'm on Kubuntu, so I can't test it either.