# setTimeOut with Parameters in IE8 not working

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

Can some one tell me where I am going wrong here, I have tested it in Firefox and Chrome and it works okay just need it working in IE8 now.

```
        setTimeout(function(it) {
            x = $('.menuheader:first-child').position().left;
            w = $('.menuheader:first-child').width();
            p = x + w + 16;
            $(it).next().css('left', p);
            $(it).next().show();
        }, 200, this);
```

Also tried...

```
        function showmenu(it){
            x = $('.menuheader:first-child').position().left;
            w = $('.menuheader:first-child').width();
            p = x + w + 16;
            $(it).next().css('left', p);
            $(it).next().show();
        }

        window.setTimeout(function() {
            showmenu(this)
        }, 200);
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007364/settimeout-issue-in-ie8

Comment: Duplicate didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct legacy way to "pass parameters" to a function that can't accept them is with a closure:

```
var that = this;
setTimeout(function(){ doStuff(that);}, 200);

function doStuff(it) {
   x = $('.menuheader:first-child').position().left;
   w = $('.menuheader:first-child').width();
   p = x + w + 16;
   $(it).next().css('left', p);
   $(it).next().show();
}
```

A newer alternative (not compatible with IE8 without a polyfill):

```
 setTimeout(doStuff.bind(null, this), 200);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: Yes thats better now with the 'that' in there.

Comment: Yeah, your second attempt didn't work because JS usually changes `this` when the function gets called. That is why you need to give it a new name when you pass `this` around through a closure.

Answer (score 1):

I've never found `setTimeout` parameters to be particularly reliable, so I just do this:

```
var it = this;
setTimeout(function() { ... }, 200);
```